# Not sure how to make this component rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@anushkas/bossy-celery) I have created a bar chart in react native that takes user input and adjusts accordingly.
[image]
For instance, If user inputs Less Than 10, only bar components less than the user entered value show up. If user enters greater than 10, user entered value greater than 10 show up.
The issue here is that the component instance is not rerendering post user selections. If I select less than 10 once, I cannot select less than 20 again the second time around. Bar component containing the value 20 is not simply there.
[image]
Is there any way to make this barchart rerender everytime a user inputs a new value and selects a new less than/greater than picker option?

```
import {Chart,LineChart,BarChart,PieChart,ProgressChart,ContributionGraph} from 'react-native-chart-kit'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Icon, FlatList, Button, TextInput, Dimensions, SafeAreaView, Picker, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default function FocusScreen() {

const [filterLimit, setfilterLimit] = useState(100);
const [lessThanOrGreaterThan, setlessThanOrGreaterThan] = useState("greaterThan");
const [datas, setDatas] = useState([12, 19, 12, 25, 22, 10])

const dataset = {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: datas,
        colors: [
          (opacity = 1) => `red`,
          (opacity = 1) => `blue`,
          (opacity = 1) => `yellow`,
          (opacity = 1) => `green`,
          (opacity = 1) => `purple`,
          (opacity = 1) => `orange`,
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

const applyFilter = () => {
    const isLessThan = lessThanOrGreaterThan === "greaterThan";
    const value = filterLimit;
    // update instance variable
    const newDatas = datas.map(v => {
    if (isLessThan ? v >= value : v <= value) return v;
        return 0;
    });
    setDatas(newDatas);
}

return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.chartContainer}>
      <BarChart
              data={dataset}
              width={300}
              height={220}
              withCustomBarColorFromData={true}
              flatColor={true}
              chartConfig={{
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                backgroundGradientFrom: '#ffffff',
                backgroundGradientTo: '#ffffff',
                data: dataset.datasets,
                color: (opacity = 1) => '#fff',
                labelColor: () => '#6a6a6a',
              }}
            />
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          numeric
          placeholder="Filter Limit"
          value={filterLimit}
          onChangeText={text => setfilterLimit(text)}
        />
      </View>
    <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={lessThanOrGreaterThan}
          style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setlessThanOrGreaterThan(itemValue)}
        >
          <Picker.Item label ="Greater Than" value="greaterThan" />
          <Picker.Item label="Less Than" value="lessThan" />
        </Picker>
      </View>
       <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
        <Button
          onPress={() => applyFilter()}
          title = "Apply Filter"
          color="#841584"
      />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
);
}
```

Comment: You set `setlessThanOrGreaterThan` to a  string. Then on `valuechange` you set it to a `number` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think the logic inside `applyFilter` is incorrect why?
`datas` are the filtered data (*in the first it's all records, but if you apply filters then `datas` will be filtered records, so next time you use the filtered data, not all data*) not all the data records, so you should have to keep all the records, somewhere and you cant change it, because  you have to filter from the all of the records.

Then we should have a function to be called every time when `lessThanOrGreaterThan` or `filterLimit` change

```
useEffect(() => {
    applyFilter();
}, [lessThanOrGreaterThan, filterLimit]);
```

[updated example](https://snack.expo.io/P!Ue_GJsr8)

If you want to rerender the graph when a user click on the `APPLY FILTER` button then you don't need above `useEffect`, only thing you need to do is keep all the data record in non-changeable place and filter those all records based on the selected filters, and set to the state.

[Example](https://snack.expo.io/hMhvk30dE)